# how do you uninstall an xampp installation that refuses to uninstall?

Tags: windows-7, installation, xampp, uninstall

I downloaded xampp 1.7.3 (32) on windows 7 (64) in the programs(86) folder. both MySql and Apache refuse to run, they start and then instantly turn of. All ports are free.

So I decide to uninstall however, when i run the uninstaller I receive the following error

```
"Input Error: Can not find script file "C:\Program Files (x86)\xampp\uninst.temp\xampp_uninstall.vbs" XAMPP uninstall not OK
```

Why is there spaces in the above line and does this matter "C:\Program Files (x86)" ?

Can somebody please help me to understand the problem & uninstall xampp (or get it to work). It does not show in the control panel so I am stuck.

All help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the file and pretend the installation never happened. Or system restore :-(